# VS Code Terminal prompt starts with " (base) computer-name:filepath " and not just " username:~/filepath/ "

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I just started a Udemy course on Node.js. The following is not for an assignment, but just an issue with the environment. I'm learning Node.js in order to finish my grad diploma capstone project (yes, I've also asked within the course).

I'm on a MacBook Pro running MacOS Big Sur 11.6, VS Code Version: 1.61.0, Node.js v.16.11.1

My terminal in VS Code doesn't start with the same style of prompt as in the videos (or that my Mac terminal has done the last time I used it months ago).

```
(base) Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:NODE-COURSE elizabethmccready$ cd notes-app

(base) Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro:notes-app elizabethmccready$ node app.js
```

Ccreenshot of my terminal window in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Instead of:

```
elizabethmccready:~/filepath
```

My MacBook terminal also has a different prompt:

```
elizabethmccready@Elizabeths-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

instead of:

```
elizabethmccready:~$
```

screenshot of MacBook terminal window

[image]

It's been almost a year since I've had to use my terminal window, so I'm really rusty. Also this is the last few weeks of my grad diploma and my brain is full.

Comment: Looks like the integrated terminal might be using bash instead of zsh, which is the new default shell as the message tells you in the integrated terminal. You can run the command it suggests and restart VSCode, or you can open the VSCode settings (JSON) (CMD+Shift+P and type settings, the choose settings (JSON)) and set `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh"` and reopen the terminal.

Comment: Don't worry that the prompt is different - just use `pwd` to see what folder you are in, and `ls` to see what  is in the current folder. Given that your `node <script>` command is not producing any errors, it looks like this is working you - unless you were expecting your script to produce console output?